# How do I use PathMatcher::matchPath() for a wildcard path?

Tags: 8, theming

I am trying to use [`PathMatcher::matchPath()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Path%21PathMatcher.php/function/PathMatcher%3A%3AmatchPath/8.2.x) to match a string of paths using a wildcard pattern.

I'd like to match any path containing `/topic*` so if the path matches, I'd like to add a body class for pages that have `/topic`, `/topic/foo`, `/topic/bar`, etc..

The code I am using is the following.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_html(array &$vars) {
  // Define the current path.
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  // Define the pattern using a string.
  $patterns = "/topic/*";
  // If the path matches the pattern.
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->matchPath($current_path, $patterns)) {
    $vars['attributes']['class'][] = 'is-topic';
  }
}
```

The code doesn't work to match this pattern so no class is added when I am on any of these pages.

My Xdebug info is as follows for the page that has the path `topic/review-procedures`

```
$current_path = /node/62
$path_alias = topic/review-procedures
```

Note that some pages with `/topic/` in the path will not be nodes however, that is why I am trying to do the path matching.

Am I correctly using `PathMatcher::matchPath()`?

Comment: _doesn't work_ is a broad statement. What exactly doesn't work as expected? How you are calling `matchPath()` is how Drupal core calls that method, and how the example in the documentation page does.

Comment: Updated summary as to why it does not work.

Comment: It looks a bit as if matchPath maybe is only looking at internal paths or route names? What does `\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath()` return you? Install the Devel submodule Kint and tell us what `ksm(\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath());` inside that preprocess function returns you on the screen when visiting a relevant path. Is topic a node type for itself? Then you could check the route parameter to get the node, from there you have the type and can add a body class.

Comment: @leymannxI added my xdebug output above.

Comment: What I expected. Try to get the current path alias. Maybe the patch matcher works with aliases. Is it a dedicated node type you are talking about?

Comment: It's pretty much what @leymannx said - the `path.current` service gets you the raw, un-aliased path , whereas you need to be matching against the alias

Comment: I added in the summary above that some pages will not be nodes that have `/topic/` in the URL, that is why I am trying to do a pattern match, otherwise, I would just use the existing node type body classes that Drupal provides.

Comment: You'll need to do both - look for a node object in the current route parameters, if you find one test against the URL alias (if it's still even required after testing the content type etc). Once you've eliminated that possibility, check against the current system path if you still need to. You may also need to add a `url.path` cache context, but being at the top level of html.html.twig it might already be covered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your sample you were comparing the internal path (/node/123) with a path alias pattern (/topic/*). This won't work. You need to do the matching with the path alias instead.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $current_alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->matchPath($current_alias, '/topic/*')) {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'is-topic';
  }
}
```

You could achieve the same by exploding the current request URI and then see if the first key is `topic`.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $request_uri = ltrim(\Drupal::request()->getRequestUri(), '/');
  $args = explode('/', $request_uri);
  if (isset($args[0]) && $args[0] === 'topic') {
    $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'is-topic';
  }
}
```

Comment: These are both excellent, thank you! I also found this https://www.advomatic.com/insights/theming-drupal-8-pages-based-on-url which does pretty much what I need as well.

Comment: @DannyEnglander – Ah yes, looks pretty similar. Thanks for sharing!